# Django "SuspiciousOperation" Error While Deleting Uploaded File

Tags: python, windows, django

I'm developing in Django on Windows XP using the `manage.py runserver` command to serve files. Apache isn't involved. When I login to the administration and try to delete a file I get a "SuspiciousOperation" error.

Here's the traceback:
http://dpaste.com/123112/

Here's my full model:
http://dpaste.com/hold/123110/

How can I get rid of this "SuspiciousOperation" error?

**EDIT:** Here are my media settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Server/Projects/postnzb/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is your `MEDIA_ROOT` in `settings.py`? From the back-trace, it seems you have set your `MEDIA_ROOT` to `/static/`.

This error is coming since Django is trying to access `/static/` to which it has no access. Put an absolute pathname for `MEDIA_ROOT` like `C:/Documents/static/` and give full permissions to Django to access that directory.

That should solve your problem.

**Addendum**: Since your `MEDIA_ROOT` seems to be OK, I am guessing that you are using `MEDIA_URL` for deleting the file instead of `MEDIA_ROOT`. Indeed, from the error it seems that Django was trying to access the `/static/files/8.nzb` and was denied access. Clearly, `/static/` is your `MEDIA_URL` and not your `MEDIA_ROOT`. The model methods should never try accessing the files using the `MEDIA_URL`. I am sure a review of your code will spot the error.

**Update**: I skimmed your code and it seems you are setting `File.nzb` to `%(1)sfiles/%(2)s.nzb' % {'1': settings.MEDIA_URL, '2': self.pk}` which uses its `MEDIA_URL` and then in the `delete()` method you are calling the `delete()` method of the super-class of `File` as `super(File, self).delete()` which is obviously wrong as it will try deleting `File.nzb` and will try accessing the file through the `MEDIA_URL`. Fixing that will get rid of the error. I will leave the exact solution as an exercise to you :)

Comment: I've added my media settings to my question description. MEDIA_ROOT is, in fact, an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks for helping my though this issue. Turns out you were completely  correct. "File.nzb" ether has to be a full path or a relative path that doesn't start with the forward slash. Since I'm going to deploy on a NIX server, I'll use relative paths. Thanks again!